# Why use $\ln$ in definition of pseudorapidity?

Tags: particle-physics

Why is pseudorapidity defined as $\eta = -\ln[\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})]$ as opposed to just $\eta = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$?

Comment: Where is your calculation demonstrating it is additive thus? Demonstrate you appreciate its linchpin property.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the concept of rapidity first, which brings in the Ln term. The same argument can be made, with more convoluted math, for pseudorapdity

Define  $y = 1/2 \ln \frac{E+p_zc}{E-p_zc}$

In collisions, the energies  involved are obviously  very high. If we make the assumption that a particular particle is made to travel along the  XY plane that is perpendicular to the direction of propagation of the beam then, 
in this case, this will result in a low value for $p_z$, with a rapidity close to 0, that is $\ln 1$.

If we instead direct the same highly relativistic part down the axis  of the beam, in the usual +z direction, then we will have a situation where  the same highly relativistic particle  travels predominantly down the beam axis, say in the +z direction. In this case, $E= p_zc$, and $y → +∞$.

The upshot of all this is that  the rapidity tends to zero when a particle is approximately transverse to the beam axis, but tends to $±∞$ when a particle is moving close to the beam axis in either direction.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.